# On hold for a valid question conforming to guidelines

Tags: discussion, support, moderation

Im certain that the answers of several of the "power members" of the community are not in a good light in this question I have asked, but they can edit their responses.

https://serverfault.com/questions/748157/what-aside-from-dns-round-robin-can-be-used-in-front-of-load-balancers-and-behin

I even had personal attacks on me. What kind of moderation is that?

Comment: I reviewed the history of this post, and I could not find any evidence of personal attacks against you there.

Answer (score 9):

You are knowingly misrepresenting the situation. The original question and the first edits didn't form a suitable question for ServerFault and it was closed for this reason. This has been explained to you in the comments. The last edit *might* make it suitable for reopening, but all comments up to my last one where made in light of the original question, all  of them valid.

You can't expect that people come back to your question and adapt their comments to the latest edit or even notice that it has been edited at all and you also can't expect that it gets reopened immediately upon you editing it. A closed question will be put in a review queue and when enough people see it there and agree, it will be reopened.

Flagging for mod attention is also possible, but moderators will not automatically reopen everything they get a flag for and quite frankly, in this case I will leave this decision up the community.

Comment: I'd say that the current question falls under the "product, service, or learning material recommendations" closure reason.

Comment: Im certain you would @JennyD since you have clearly had many issues with this posting from the start when I challenged your weak reply.

Comment: Sorry, but what was (very) weak was your question. Don't shoot the messenger.

Comment: Interesting how someone managed to give some legitimate answers and recommendations out of the final postings.

Comment: @user1669039 Firstly, the only problem that caused me to vote to close the question was the question itself. I cast my vote before you had started writing long rants in the comments; thus, they had no impact on my vote at all. Second, my comment was just that - a comment. It was not an answer, much less a complete one. Had I wanted to post an answer, I would have posted it in the Answer box, not in the comment box. Third, every comment I have posted has been about the content of your question, not about you as a person. I wish you would show the same courtesy in return.

Comment: @user1669039 Jenny is absolutely right. Remember, *you* approached *us* for help. Which means that the burden is on you to ensure that your question and your modes of communication meet our community guidelines. We also have expectations that everyone will conduct themselves in a professional, respectful manner, which you have not done. As others have mentioned, I've seen no evidence of you being the target of "personal attacks" or anything like that. I would suggest re-considering your behavior or risk being banned.

Answer (score 9):

> ...but they can edit their responses...

Unlike for questions and answers, [comments](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment) only have a have very limited window (**only 5 minutes**) when edits are allowed. After that the only remaining *"edit"* option the system allows users is the delete button.

As a moderator I don't see any evidence that comments to your question have been deleted. I can only read the comments as they currently are, the same for you and everybody else.

> I even had personal attacks on me.

I don't see anything that supports that claim, but please remember that comments are intended for short, terse and quick messages. They are not lengthy well-formatted answers. Please don't confuse any necessarily direct language for aggressive.

Comment: "No it's not "updated as per guidelines". This isn't a forum, where it would be reasonable to ask all participants to list their opinions. It's a QA, where you should ask a practical, answerable question based on actual problems that you face, including enough information that it would be reasonable for people to solve your problem. You have failed." - Jenny

Comment: @user1669039 If you consider the factually correct statement that you have failed to edit the question to conform to our guidelines as agressive then maybe you shouldn't be on the internet and try to interact with strangers.

Comment: @user1669039 If you think that saying that you failed to write a question that follows the guideline is a personal attack... then this probably is not a site where you will ever feel welcome.

Comment: @Sven The answers that eventually did arrive from helpful members were of perfect reference. If a member is going to give a vague reply such as... "It's not a substitute for an actual HA system", which had nothing to do with the question, then maybe they shouldn't be replying to a topic. Then retaliate flagging it when I call them on it.

Comment: @user1669039 Please take a few minutes to read the [help]. It will explain the  difference between comments and answers.

Comment: Also, the helpful answers came after you'd completely re-edited the question (and, incidentally, after I'd given up on it).

Comment: @user1669039: And it will also explain a lot of other things you need to learn to get the most of this (sometimes quite quirky) site.